# Makefile Rule to Move Nested Files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So I am trying to write a `Makefile` to remove files nested in directories with the same names. As an example, I have a directory with two files whose paths are `./1234/1234.txt` and `./567/567.txt`. I want to move those files up to the top directory so that they are just `./1234.txt` and `./567.txt`. I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
variable = ./1234/1234.txt ./567/567.txt

run: $(variable)

$(variable): $$(notdir %): %
    mv $< $@
```

It seems like something that would be a common problem but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Thanks so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your targets the wrong way round, and trying to use functions in a rule won't work unless you use secondary expansion. You'll also need to conditionally add the dependencies because otherwise your rule will give an error if you've already moved the files.

```
variable = ./1234.txt ./567.txt

run: $(variable)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(variable): ./%.txt: $$(wildcard ./$$*/$$*.txt)
    mv $< $@
```